# Command Line Option to Activate Airflow DAGs

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, airflow

We have a continuous integration pipeline which automatically deploys our Airflow DAGs to the Airflow server. When a new version of a DAG is deployed, its status is **OFF** by default. We would like to turn it **ON** as part of the tasks executed by the deployment process.

Is there a command line option in Airflow which allows to turn ON a DAG?
Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok it seems I did not look carefully enough. The answer is just here in [Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html)

You can turn **OFF** a DAG with the following command:

```
$ airflow pause <dag_id>
```

You can turn **ON** a DAG with the following command:

```
$ airflow unpause <dag_id>
```

Update:
The command `airflow unpause` has been removed.

You should now use

```bash
$ airflow dags unpause <dag_id>
```

instead of

```bash
$ airflow unpause <dag_id>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you say new version, I am assuming you change the DAG_ID, have you consider to update the airflow.cfg to
`dags_are_paused_at_creation = False`?

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. What I mean by a new version of a DAG is I update an existing dag_id. The solution you propose could have been an option indeed but in my case I do not have access to airflow.cfg, and because it’s a mutualized instance of Airflow, other users might not want to change the ‘dags_are_paused_at_creation’ setting. By the way, do you know if versioning a DAG actually counts as a creation? Thank you