# Airflow quickstart DagRunNotFound DagRun example_bash_operator not found

Tags: airflow, virtualenv

I'm learning Airflow and just want to get up and running with the Quickstart: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html

I'm not sure if this is a virtual environment issue or something I'm missing with Airflow that should be obvious and this may be a duplicate of this question from 2017: [Running Airflow task from the command line does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639055/running-airflow-task-from-the-command-line-does-not-work) but there were no answers there.

My OS is POP_OS (debian)

I have created a new virtual environment and installed airflow by running the script provided:

```
# Airflow needs a home. `~/airflow` is the default, but you can put it
# somewhere else if you prefer (optional)
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

# Install Airflow using the constraints file
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.5.0
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
# For example: 3.7
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"
# For example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.5.0/constraints-3.7.txt
pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"

# The Standalone command will initialise the database, make a user,
# and start all components for you.
airflow standalone

# Visit localhost:8080 in the browser and use the admin account details
# shown on the terminal to login.
# Enable the example_bash_operator dag in the home page
```

I was expecting this to be plug-and-play and I haven't even reached the tutorials yet.

`airflow standalone` works and I can run the DAG from the web UI. However, if I run

```
# run your first task instance
airflow tasks run example_bash_operator runme_0 2015-01-01
```

from the CLI, I get

```
airflow.exceptions.DagRunNotFound: DagRun for example_bash_operator with run_id or execution_date of '2015-01-01' not found
```

full error:

```
(airflow) jasonstewartnz@pop-os:~$ airflow tasks run example_bash_operator runme_0 2015-01-01
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,776] {dagbag.py:538} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/jasonstewartnz/airflow/dags
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,820] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): create_entry_group>, delete_entry_group already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,820] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): delete_entry_group>, create_entry_group already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,820] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): create_entry_gcs>, delete_entry already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,820] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): delete_entry>, create_entry_gcs already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,820] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): create_tag>, delete_tag already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,820] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(BashOperator): delete_tag>, create_tag already registered for DAG: example_complex
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,832] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,832] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,833] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,833] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,833] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,833] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,833] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): print_the_context>, log_sql_query already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,833] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): log_sql_query>, print_the_context already registered for DAG: example_python_operator
/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:3492 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: Param `schedule_interval` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `schedule` instead.
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,914] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): prepare_email>, send_email already registered for DAG: example_dag_decorator
[2022-12-22 11:11:18,914] {taskmixin.py:205} WARNING - Dependency <Task(EmailOperator): send_email>, prepare_email already registered for DAG: example_dag_decorator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 384, in task_run
    ti, _ = _get_ti(task, args.map_index, exec_date_or_run_id=args.execution_date_or_run_id, pool=args.pool)
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 159, in _get_ti
    dag_run, dr_created = _get_dag_run(
  File "/home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 115, in _get_dag_run
    raise DagRunNotFound(
airflow.exceptions.DagRunNotFound: DagRun for example_bash_operator with run_id or execution_date of '2015-01-01' not found
```

The web UI tells me my config is `/home/jasonstewartnz/airflow/airflow.cfg`
The `dags_folder` in this `/home/jasonstewartnz/airflow/dags` is empty.

When I go to
http://localhost:8080/dags/example_bash_operator/details

I see that the fileloc attribute for the dag is:

fileloc     /home/jasonstewartnz/.venv/airflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_bash_operator.py

Even if I copy this file to the DAGs directory or change the DAGs directory in the config to the above, or add it to the path the CLI still seems unable to find the DAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you enable the DAG, 'example_bash_operator' in the UI as the instructions specify? I am referring to this step in the guide's instructios:

```
# Visit localhost:8080 in the browser and use the admin account details
# shown on the terminal to login.
# Enable the example_bash_operator dag in the home page
```

This should be done before you attempt to execute command, `airflow tasks run`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks like this was it. I thought it said you can do it via the Web UI or by running the task from the CLI. Is there a way to set enabled from the CLI?

Comment: I believe there is a way using the `unpause` CLI command. More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426494/command-line-option-to-activate-airflow-dags